# Autoconfigure Error: g_multi: waiting for /sys/class/net/usb0/

Tags: debian, network-interface, journalctl

I am receiving a new systemd journal message on my debian linux system. It is as follows:

```
Nov 30 20:41:42 beaglebone sh[628]: autoconfigure_usb0.sh: g_multi: waiting for /sys/class/net/usb0/
```

This message repeats every couple seconds and I am unsure what has caused it. I can find little online regarding this message. Seems that some service has run the `autoconfigure_usb0.sh` script but it is clearly not working. Has something to do with the network interface. I am currently connected to a functioning wifi with internet access. The `autoconfigure_usb0.sh` script can be seen below:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ cat /usr/bin/autoconfigure_usb0.sh
#!/bin/bash
#
# Copyright (c) 2017 David Lechner <david@lechnology.com>
#
# Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
# of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
# in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
# to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
# copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
# furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
#
# The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
# all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
#
# THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
# IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
# FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
# AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
# LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
# OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
# THE SOFTWARE.
#

if [ -f /etc/default/bb-boot ] ; then
        . /etc/default/bb-boot
fi

#Backup...
if [ "x${USB_CONFIGURATION}" = "x" ] ; then
        USB0_ADDRESS=192.168.7.2
        USB0_NETMASK=255.255.255.252
fi

#
# Auto-configuring the usb1 network interface:
#
# usb1 is the CDC/ECM gadget connection. It is managed by ConnMan and uses
# tethering so that it serves a DHCP address to attached hosts. The IPv4 subnet
# used by ConnMan is not consistent, so hosts should connect using the mDNS
# name (beaglebone.local) instead of an IP address.
#

until [ -d /sys/class/net/usb0/ ] ; do
        sleep 1
        echo "autoconfigure_usb0.sh: g_multi: waiting for /sys/class/net/usb0/"
done

# gadget is not supported by ConnMan provisioning files, so we have to do this
# the ugly way. Advanced users can comment these line to gain full control of
# the usb1 network interface.
#connmanctl enable gadget >/dev/null 2>&1
#connmanctl tether gadget on >/dev/null 2>&1

# if there is any pre-existing config for usb1, use that;
# otherwise use a static default
grep -rqE '^\s*iface usb0 inet' /etc/network/interfaces* && /sbin/ifup usb0 \
        || /sbin/ifconfig usb0 ${USB0_ADDRESS} netmask ${USB0_NETMASK} \
        || true
```

I am hoping someone with more experience in this area can help me figure out what exactly is going on here. Thanks!

**EDIT:** The output of the following command is listed below:

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ ls /sys/class/net
can0  can1  lo  SoftAp0  wlan0
```

Comment: The script is waiting for `/sys/class/net/usb0` directory. But given that you said *"This message repeats every couple seconds "* then the directory `/sys/class/net/usb0/` does not exist.

Comment: Add to your question the output of this command: `ls /sys/class/net`

Comment: I have added the requested information. It seems you are correct and the /usb0/ directory does not exist. I am not sure if this was recently deleted somehow, or if the service that requests it was recently activated. Either way this message is new. I currently use the wlan0 connection.

Comment: As you said you are using `wlan0` interface then I suppose you could change this line: `until [ -d /sys/class/net/usb0/ ] ; do` to `until [ -d /sys/class/net/wlan0/ ] ; do`